# XPath and CSS in Oxygen XML Author: How to create a dynamic parameter in oxy_xpath

Tags: css, xpath, oxygenxml

I am creating an Oxygen framework to display XML data in Oxygen XML Author's author mode. This is part of the XML I have with two nodes <ab> in it:

```
<TEI>
<text>
    <body>
        <div n="A">
            <ab xml:id="n_d2e23" type="person">
                <seg type="name">
                    <persName>
                        <surname>Aarberg</surname>,
                        <forename>Peter von</forename>
                    </persName>
                    <roleName>König</roleName>
                    (<date from="ca. 1300" to="vor 1372">ca. 1300–vor 1372</date>)
                </seg>
                <seg type="affiliations">
                    <list>
                        <item>
                            <affiliation role="CEO" hkg:orgKey="#n_123_456">Best CEO they ever had</affiliation>
                        </item>
                    </list>
                </seg>
            </ab>

            <ab xml:id="n_123_456" source="SW_EB" type="organization">
                <seg type="name">
                    <orgName>Altenburger Hofdruckerei</orgName>
                </seg>
            </ab>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

The first <ab> node has an attribute *hkg:orgKey="#n_123_456"* which is referring to the second <ab> node's attribute *xml:id="n_123_456"*. I use the following CSS to display the value of <orgName> of the second <ab> node in the visual representation of the first <ab> node in Oxygen XML Author:

```
affiliation:after {
content: " role: " oxy_textfield(
    edit, "@role")
    " Organization ID: " oxy_textfield(
    edit, "@hkg:orgKey")
    "Organization name: " oxy_xpath(
        "/TEI/text/body/div/ab[@xml:id='n_123_456']/seg[@type='name']/orgName/text()"
    )
    " " oxy_url("gfx/link_register.png");
    link: attr("hkg:orgKey")
}
```

This works fine and the value of <orgName> of the 2nd <ab> node, in fact "Altenburger Hofdruckerei", is displayed within the first <ab> node - as long as I use the concrete value *hkg:orgKey="#n_123_456"*. But now I need to create the line

```
/TEI/text/body/div/ab[@xml:id='n_123_456']/seg[@type='name']/orgName/text()
```

dynamically which means: Instead of the specific value *xml:id=n_123_456* it should use whatever the value of the *attribute @hkg:orgKey* of the node <ab> of the 1st element <ab> is. I tried this:

```
/TEI/text/body/div/ab[@xml:id=@hkg:orgKey]/seg[@type='name']/orgName/text()
```

but it doesn't work. I also tried other variations like *ab[@xml:id='@hkg:orgKey']* or *ab[@xml:id=attr('hkg:orgKey')]* and many more but none of them gave me the expected result.

Maybe it is a syntax problem. I really hope there will be a solution to this and I would be very thankful for assistance. Any help is appreciated.

I tried to send as much code as needed but of course shortened some parts not relevant in this context. If something is missing (or too much) please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have already declared in the CSS a mapping for the "hkg" prefix like:

```
  @namespace hkg "someNamespace";
```

I would replace:

```
link: attr("hkg:orgKey")
```

with:

```
 link: attr(hkg|orgKey);
```

because in CSS you refer to namespaced elements with "prefix|elementName" instead of "prefix:elementName".

As for the main question, this line:

```
 oxy_xpath("/TEI/text/body/div/ab[@xml:id='n_123_456']/seg[@type='name']/orgName/text()")
```

with:

```
 oxy_xpath(oxy_concat("/TEI/text/body/div/ab[@xml:id='", oxy_substring(attr(hkg|orgKey), 1), "']/seg[@type='name']/orgName/text()"))
```

I'm using oxy_concat to step outside of the string literal, evaluate the attribute value and use its value in the larger XPath expression. I used "oxy_substring" to remove the "#" from the attribute reference.